# Malloc inside Kernel

Tags: malloc, cuda

I am trying to compile a code that has a malloc function inside the kernel
and i get this error:

```
Error   5   error : calling a host function("malloc") from a __device__/__global__ function("bitapS") is not allowed    C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.0\C\src\str_bit\main.cu    36  1   str_bit
```

My command line is:

```
Error   6   error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64" -I"../../common/inc" -I"../../../shared/inc" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\include"  -G0  --keep-dir "x64\Debug" -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile  -D_NEXUS_DEBUG -g    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /nologo /Od /Zi  /MTd " -o "x64/Debug/main.cu.obj" "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.0\C\src\str_bit\main.cu"" exited with code 2.   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 4.0.targets  357 10  str_bit
```

Any suggestions? I thought that with sm_20 enabled you could allocate... my card is a 460 GTX
Thanks!

Comment: I see the potential problem with -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" declaration, are you sure it doesn't take precedence?

Comment: With ```-gencode```, ```nvcc``` compiles the code for *all* of the supplied architectures and creates a 'fat binary'. So the error occurs when it compiles the code containing ```malloc``` for ```sm_10```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it....
You have to specify 
sm_20,compute_20
also to your file properties not only in the project attributes!

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

It's true you should not do it but if they enabled it probably has some uses.
The code gives an error because you are compiling for architecture 1.0 and 2.0. To make it compile you can remove

```
-gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\"
```

from the command line if you only intend to run the code on fermi devices or you must provide an alternative code in your source code for older devices. You can do it by using the NVCC preprocessor macro:

```
__CUDA_ARCH__
```

like this:

```
#if (__CUDA_ARCH__ < 200)
/* code for 1.x arch */
#else
/* code for 2.x arch */
#endif
```

It seems you are using Visual Studio so in the project properties you can go to the cuda section and specify there the architectures you wan't to build for.

Answer (score -4):

You should not be allocating memory inside the kernel. Ever. This is a clear sign your CUDA kernel is poorly designed and will have bad performance.

Comment: you can! Read teh Specs!
You have to specify 
sm_20,compute_20
also to your file!

Thanks anyway!

Comment: @iassael Maybe you can, but I still bet its a bad idea performance wise. Since all your inputs to the kernel have to come from the host anyways (or are static), you can do all your calculations on the host side to allocate the right amount of memory.

Comment: @iassael: onit is both correct and incorrect: he is incorrect in saying that you can't allocate memory dynamically inside kernels at runtime on devices of compute capability 2.0; he is right in saying that you really, really, really shouldn't be doing it if you care about performance, which seems like a reasonable assumption given that you're using CUDA and GPUs in the first place.

Comment: Edited my post. Allowing this must be a relatively new feature that I wasn't aware of. I still stand by my comment that you probably shouldn't be doing this.